# Don't see a div into a vue component

Tags: laravel, button, vue.js, components

I have a vue component with a div and a button and into another div I have two components

```js
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'excursion-backend-component',
        methods:{
            doRedirection: function () {
                window.location = APP_URL+"/excursiones/create";
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log(APP_URL+"/excursiones/create");
            console.log("aaaa");
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Adicionar excursi&oacute;n</h3>
        <div style="text-align: right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" :href="doRedirection"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Adicionar</a>
        </div>
        <br>

        <div>
            <excursion-list-component></excursion-list-component>
            <excursion-add-component></excursion-add-component>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

But I don't see the button on the navigator.

What is wrong?

[Here is how I see the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI314.png)

Comment: Ufff sorry, I called excursion-list-component component on view laravel. The right way is put the general component. (for moderator. if you want delete this question...)

Comment: You can answer your own question, if you think it a good question and is helpful to other users. If it's a basic typo, then I will vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

:href="" expecting string with url to navigation, but you using method.

Use @click instead :href, if you want to use method.

```
<a @click="doRedirect">... </a>
```

Or, may be, move it to computed block

```
computed: {
    excursionesUrl () {
      return APP_URL+"/excursiones/create";
   }
}
```